# How to translate "makenai" (負けない)

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, expressions, translation

We are creating an English brochure where we put our slogan, "gan ni makenai shakai wo tsukuru" (がんに負けない社会をつくる）, looking for a most appropriate English expression for ”がんに負けない”. We don't mean coping with cancer is a win-or-lose battle but do want to express more positive attitude of cancer patients and the society.
Any help of advise is most welcome. Thank you.

Comment: This is the **English** Stack Exchange.  I think you need to provide at least a crude translation into English.

Comment: Almost nobody here speaks Japanese: I can only think of two or three. Please edit your post to help us know what you want. If you can do that, then we can reopen it and help you. Thank you.

Comment: A little bird has told me *“負ける makeru is 'lose', and 負けない makenai is the negative form of that. がんに負けない社会をつくる literally means "mak[ing] a society which doesn't lose to cancer".”* Is that more about what you are looking for? Something about society having a positive attitude toward beating cancer?

Comment: I would suggest that you avoid trying to reinvent the wheel.  Take a look at existing materials in English about fighting cancer.  There should be some sentences in a brochure that gives you the positive tone you're hoping to have.

Comment: As I see it, the sentence translates to "Create a society that **can live with** cancer". HTH.

Comment: There are quite a few (plenty of) similar questions essentially about an English word, phrase or idiom corresponding to a Japanese one. What's so different with this to close?

Comment: “Don’t get cancer, don’t lose to cancer, and strive for a society that can live with cancer.” National Cancer Center, Japan. https://www.pfizer.com/sites/default/files/funded_initiative_proposal/35682941%20National%20Cancer%20Center%20Japan%20Full%20Proposal.pdf p.4

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about English.

Comment: ELU is not a good site for recommending or proofreading good translations  into English. You may want to try https://japanese.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

If **がんに負けない社会をつくる** literally means ~ 'making a society which doesn't lose to cancer' or 'a society that can live with cancer, searching for an English expression of same is a broad request.

This page includes many such 'battling cancer' sites: [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=phrases%20to%20fight%20cancer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1).  As you develop your brochure, I suggest a native English speaking editor peruse your work.